# Using 2 NSPersistentContainer

Tags: swift, core-data, nspersistentstore, nspersistentcontainer

Is it possible to have multiple NSPersistentContainer hooked up to the same store in a project. Im changing an existing implementation which uses 2 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator to use NSPersistentContainer.